# Why is an HTML tag 'closing itself' in javascript and not including iterated content?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, innerhtml

I am trying to open an HTML tag, iterate a for loop to add content from an array, then after the loop is created, close the HTML tag.

However I am seeing that it renders the HTML tag opening and closing and then the iterated content outside the HTML tag.

Example:

```
    block.innerHTML += "<span id='span-" + counterFunction() + "' class='someClass'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        block.innerHTML += letterArray[i] + ", ";
    }
        block.innerHTML += "___?</span>";
```

What I'd got was:

```
    <span id='span-1' class='someClass'></span>
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, ___?
```

What I'D expected was:

```
    <span id='span-1' class='someClass'>a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, ___?</span>
```

I am interested why it appears as though the closing tag is parsed out from the `.innerHTML` following the `for loop`.

Note:
I did get some advice, and solved it by declaring variables for everything, and then only using `.innerHTML` one time.

```
    var openSpan = "<span id='span-" + variable + "' class='someSpan'>";
    var closeSpan = "___?</span>";
    var arrayAsString = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        arrayAsString += letterArray[i] + ", ";
    }
    block.innerHTML += (openSpan + arrayAsString + closeSpan);
```

But I am still wondering what went wrong on my first logic

Comment: Because setting innetHTML triggers creation of the DOM objects you're inserting. (see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Since valid answer is given all that is left is to inform you how to avoid this problem. It's simple.

 - Either you do all the things that change inner content before and
   only then insert entire innerHTML into DOM.
 - or you create element, then place it in correct place in DOM.